# Variable height cell in UITableView works only when the cell is out of view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make variable height cell using auto layout in UITableView. The table view cell has two labels: title label and description label.

```
var viewBindingsDict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
viewBindingsDict.setValue(myTitleLabel, forKey: "label")
viewBindingsDict.setValue(myDescriptionLabel, forKey: "description")
let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[label]-10-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]) as [AnyObject]
let horizontalConstraints2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[description]-10-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]) as [AnyObject]
let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[label]-5-[description]-10-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]) as [AnyObject]
self.contentView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints + horizontalConstraints2 + verticalConstraints)
```

And in the table view controller,

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In table view's data source,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! MyCell

    // setup cell

    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

This works for most cells but there are always one or two cells not properly laid out. For example, in this [test project](https://github.com/nicnocquee/VariableHeightTableViewCell), the first row is not correctly arranged, but when I scroll to the bottom (the first row out of the view), then scroll back up, it fixes itself. I tried using both XIB and programmatically create the cell. But no luck.

[image]

Any idea? Please see the [test project](https://github.com/nicnocquee/VariableHeightTableViewCell) to see this weird behaviour.

Comment: try not use `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight`

Comment: I tried your code in github and it worked as expected. What is Swift version and iOS version your simulator runs on?

Comment: start your app in the simulator and then try "Debug View Hierarchy" option located at the bottom of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

See the fix in the updated version;
http://www.filedropper.com/upadtedvariableheighttableviewcell-master

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the real source of the problem is cell's frame's width is not correctly set until it's displayed on the screen, i.e., `MyCell` is always initiated with 320 points frame's width. Since the table view calculate the height of the rows before the cells are displayed, this causes problem when the app is run in iPhone 6 or 6 plus where the width is not 320 points. So I added the following code at the beginning of `setupSubviews` function in `MyCell` class.

```
self.frame.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.width
```

And now the cells are displayed shown in correct heights as soon as the table view is displayed.

And in order to solve this problem when using XIB, I override the `awakeFromNib`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // we need to set the cell's width so that content view's width will be set correctly
    self.frame.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.width
}
```

I have updated the [test project](https://github.com/nicnocquee/VariableHeightTableViewCell) if anybody's interested.